Effects of lowering the pegs on a squat
My gym has a Kabuki Strength Transformer bar.

It is an amazing device that has the ability to swivel the pegs around so it simulates different types of squats.  For example, I can distribute the weight to the front so I can do front squats without hurting my elbows, so I can swivel it back to simulate a back squat without putting so much strain on my aging shoulders.
However, one feature it has is to raise and lower the pegs. The pegs up high are closer to an actual barbell, and the lift is overall easier. The pegs down low make it more of a cambered bar and it's significantly harder.
Is there any benefit to making the squat harder by moving the pegs lower? Why would I choose to do this over simply adding more weight to the bar? What weakness is this designed to address?

I don't think it's so much addressing a weakness as it is simulating different types of squats/movements/bars with the same piece of equipment. Having the peg up high makes it like a traditional squat bar, moving the pegs lower simulates a cambered bar. Saves on equipment costs is about all I can see.

@JohnP Right, but what would anyone incorporate this in to training when the higher up pegs are already an option?  Seems more of a gimmick, but I am wondering if there's a more valid reason.
